# Open 2 apps with nw.js

Tags: javascript, nw.js, nwjs

How to open 2 different apps with nw.js, if `"single-instance": false` (http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/References/Manifest%20Format/#single-instance) is deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

Just launch 2 NW.js instances with 2 different apps respectively. `single-instance` was for the scenario when there is only 1 app.

Comment: When i launch the first app, the second does not launch

Answer (score 0):

I change the name of second app, and finally, it works.